# Full screen window only covers taskbar when Aero (Windows 7) is turned off when DPI is set to 150%

Tags: c, windows, winapi, dpi, aero

I have a fairly standard C++ program where I create a fullscreen window (with two child windows). On my development computer with Windows 10 this window fills the entire screen and covers the taskbar.

On Windows 7 it does not cover the task-bar. After some experimenting it seems that if I turn off Aero the program will cover the taskbar!

I've also created a quick C#/WPF application and this application is able to cover the taskbar regardless of the state of Aero.

Am I missing a window message or creation option for the window?

*Here is the code that positions and creates the Window*

```
// Get a handle to the primary monitor, which by definition has its top
// left corner at (0, 0).
const POINT ptZero = { 0, 0 };
HMONITOR hmon = MonitorFromPoint(ptZero, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);
MONITORINFO mi = { sizeof(mi) };
GetMonitorInfo(hmon, &mi);

// Fill the entire screen
layout->left   = mi.rcMonitor.left;
layout->right  = mi.rcMonitor.right;
layout->top    = mi.rcMonitor.top;
layout->bottom = mi.rcMonitor.bottom; 

// Create a full screen window
m_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
  WS_EX_TOPMOST,
  className,
  windowName,
  WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE,
  layout.left,
  layout.top,
  layout.right - layout.left,
  layout.bottom - layout.top,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  GetModuleHandle(NULL),
  this); // LPARAM is used in WM_CREATE to associate the class instance with the Window
```

*Here is the code that handles the Window messages*

```
switch (uMsg)
{
case WM_PAINT:
    OnPaint(hwnd); // Draws a black background 
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

**Update:**
After some Googling I found that this issue might also be DPI related: http://forums.pcsx2.net/Thread-Fullscreen-Windows-7-Taskbar-does-not-auto-hide-w-aero
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/5dMYLChXeWk

What works and doesn't work at this moment:

Areo + DPI @ 150%: taskbar not covered
No Areo + DPI @ !150%: taskbar covered
Areo + DPI @ 100%: taskbar covered
No Area + DPI @ 100%: taskbar covered

This got me pretty baffled...

Comment: Get familiar with the Spy++ utility, you can see the style flags that the C# app uses.

Comment: Have you tried adding `WS_MAXIMIZE`? And maybe `WS_EX_TOPMOST` will help as well.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, I'll check it out. @SimonKraemer, I'm already using `WS_EX_TOPMOST` (though it shouldn't be needed). I'll try `WS_MAXIMIZE` as well.

Comment: I don't suppose I could summon @RaymondChen here? :). According to thim I shouldn't have to think so hard about this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050505-04/?p=35703/

Answer (score 0):

After I found out that DPI has a role to play I stumbled upon the solution. We need to tell Windows that our application is DPI aware. If we do not do this Windows will try to rescale the UI elements of our application. I still do not know why this only causes problems when Aero is enabled but this work around fixes it:

Add a file called "manifest.xml" (name doesn't matter) to your project with the following contents:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" >
  <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
      <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

Then in the property pages change the following options for all configurations

- Linker->Manifest File
- - Generate Manifest: **Yes**
- Manifest Tool -> Input and Output
- - Additional Manifest Files: **manifest.xml**
- - Embed Manifest: **Yes**